# Twitter Bootstrap 3 and DataTables. How to apply the styling correctly with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I'm trying to apply bootstrap3 styling to my rails application, but I'm having some trouble with the DataTables styling. I know this is kind of a recurring question, but I haven't found a solution on any of them.

This is the relevant part of my .gemfile:

```
 gem 'haml'
 gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-     rails.git'
 gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
 gem 'highcharts-rails'

 gem 'therubyracer'
 gem 'less-rails'
 gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git', :branch => 'bootstrap3'
```

This is my application.js:

```
 //  require turbolinks
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require twitter/bootstrap
 //  require jquery.turbolinks

 //  require_tree .
 //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
 //= require jquery.ui.core
```

Note that I have both require_tree and turbolinks disabled.

This is my application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui.core
 *= require jquery.ui.theme
 *= require_tree .
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
 *= require special
```

The last line, 'require special', is for certain overrides I use on my website. They're not related to anything on DataTables, but to make sure, the file is currently empty.

My js.coffee table has this:

```
 jQuery ->
   $('#d_table').dataTable
     sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
```

Nothing special, it's just the initialization for the table.

And I get this:

[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

In case you're wondering, this is the code that generated that table (in HAML):

```
 %table#d_table
   %thead
     %tr
       %th='Field1'
       %th='Field2'
       %th='Field3'
       %th='Field4'
       %th='Field5'
   %tbody
     - (1..70).each do
       %tr
         - (1..5).each do |a|
           %td="This is #{a}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bootstrap a table inherits all of its styles from the `.table` class.

Try adding the class `.table` to the table element.

[Bootstrap 3 tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)

Comment: That's exactly what it was. Thank you! I guess I should read the documentation a little more.